# django , unable to upload file to a directory using filefield ,

Tags: django, file-upload

am new to django . and am really confused right now .

So i have a code which should upload a file to UPLOAD directory . from their it will be used for furthur processing . But currently am not able to push the file in filefield to UPLOAD directory
I did a deep search but was not able to find any related solution to this .

so below is my code :

```
class Files(models.Model):
    files_to_upload = models.FileField(upload_to='UPLOAD/', default = None, validators=[validate_file])
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    server = MultiSelectField(choices=server_list)

    snippet = models.ForeignKey(Snippet, related_name = "files", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.snippet)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "files"
```

and in files.html:
.`<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'files' %}" method="POST">`
i gave this too as instructed by one stack question answer .

Is there any other thing i should check

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: hi @iklinac , but i wanted it using  models.FileField(upload_to= , and i checked this too , but still am not able to :(